# how to extract a specific paragraph tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the contents of this response:

```
<div class="bio-container">
   <p class="bio profile" >
       Chinedu is a good boy
   </p>
</div>
```

Please assume there are also other paragrpah tags with different class attributes, but i want to extract this one with the class attribute "bio-profile"

I just want to extract Chinedu is a good boy to a file.

I tried `desc = bs.find ('p', {'class' : 'bio profile'})`

But not working

This is my exact code that I am trying to apply the answer for the above to:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import string


httpResponse = urllib.urlopen("https://twitter.com/drericcole")
html = httpResponse.read()
bs = bsoup(html)
desc = bs.find("p", class_="bio profile-field")
print desc.get_text().strip()
```

But i get an error statement

```
print desc.get_text().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: Change `"bio profile-field"` to `"bio profile"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `.get_text()` method on `desc`. Using Python 2.7 and BS 4.3.2:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

ofile = open("test.html")
soup = bsoup(ofile)

desc = soup.find("p", class_="bio profile")
# or desc = soup.find("p", {"class":"bio profile"})
print desc.get_text().strip()
```

Result:

```
Chinedu is a good boy
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean, "find my exact code below"? My approach is extracting the correct tag, is it not?

Comment: you are right, I have added the exact code to the question. Please help with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use BeautifulSoup module to extract all text from `<p>` tags.

**Content of script.py:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys 

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')

    print(' '.join(map(lambda e: e.string, soup.find_all('p'))))
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py infile
```

Comment: but there are other paragraph tags with the html code, how can i just get this particular one

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(<Your html>)
soup.p.text
```